# Stop automatic updating for MySQL datestamp

Tags: mysql, datestamp

I have a `datetime` column called `create_date`. When I create a row, I enter the date NOW().

However, when I update a row my `create_date` column automatically updates to NOW().  Even if I was setting different columns and not touching `create_date`, it still gets updated. How can I stop this behavior?

Found this doc, but it doesn't explain how to stop the automatic updating.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Comment: What version of MySQL are you running? It sounds like you are running 5.6.5 Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the schema so that it uses the DEFAULT clause, which sets it on creation but not on an update:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY COLUMN columnamre TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```